# Python, Pandas create a combination of value in the same column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, product

I'm tring to create a new dataframe that is a combination of all the different txt with the same id as shown below.
I tried to use .protuct but  i'have not manage to take into account that it should only be considered for the same id.

| id | txt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 1 | A2 |
| 1 | A3 |
| 2 | A4 |
| 2 | A5 |

| id | txt | txt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | A2 |
| 1 | A1 | A3 |
| 1 | A2 | A3 |
| 2 | A4 | A5 |

Do you have any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in the `itertools` library as below.

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'A1'), (1, 'A2'), (1, 'A3'), (2, 'A4'), (2, 'A5')], columns=['id', 'txt'])

output_data = []
for group_id, group_data in input_df.groupby('id'):
    for elem in list(combinations(list(group_data['txt']), 2)):
        output_data.append((group_id, *elem))
    
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=['id', 'txt1', 'txt2'])
output_df
```

The other approach would be using pandas
[`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with **user defined function**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer, it worked well.
However, I'm facing another problem yet

My dataframe look more like something like this:

```
|id|txt|num|
|:-|:-:|-:|
|1|A1|b1|
|1|A2|b2|
|1|A3|b3|
|2|A4|b4|
|2|A5|b5|
```

and I'd like to take the value linked to A1,A2,... on the second dataframe:

```
|id|txt|txt2|num1|num2|
|:-|:-:|:-:|-:|-:|
|1|A1|A2|b1|b2|
|1|A1|A3|b1|b3|
|1|A2|A3|b2|b3|
|2|A4|A5|b4|b5|
```

I tried to add it the in the loop that way but it took a very long time.

```py
    for group_id, group_data in input_df.groupby('id'):
        for elem in list(combinations(list(group_data['txt']), 2)):
            output_data.append((group_id, *elem))
```

that way but it took a very long time.

```
output_data.append((group_id, *elem,df[df['txt']==(elem[0])]['num'].values[0],df[df['txt']==(elem[1])]['num'].values[0]))
```

Any other ideas to be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def f(x):
    result = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(x[col], 2)), columns=[f'{col}1', f'{col}2']) 
                        for col in ['txt', 'num']], axis=1)
    return result

df2.groupby('d').apply(f).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   d txt1 txt2 num1 num2
0  1   A1   A2   b1   b2
1  1   A1   A3   b1   b3
2  1   A2   A3   b2   b3
3  2   A4   A5   b4   b5
```